# How to read and write data in same excel using poi and for loop

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using following code to read /write , ..
I am able to read data but not able write data in it .

```
 public class RWExcelPOI {
    File src=new File("D:\\Sujit\\Automated Script\\Auto_Tuto\\TestDataPOI.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook wb;
    XSSFSheet Sheet1;
    FileOutputStream fileOut;

    public void ReadExcel1() throws Exception{


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);

        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        XSSFSheet Sheet1=wb.getSheetAt(0);


        int rowcount=Sheet1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int colcount=Sheet1.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        System.out.println("Total Number of Rows is ::"+rowcount);
        System.out.println("Total number of Col is ::"+colcount);

        for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++){


            for(int j=0;j<colcount;j++){


                String testdata1=Sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Test data from excel cell  :"+testdata1);
                wb.close();


                Cell cell = null;  
                cell = Sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j);

                cell.setCellValue("hmm");
                // Write the output to a file  
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(src);  
                wb.write(fileOut); 

            }

        }


    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        RWExcelPOI read=new RWExcelPOI();
        read.ReadExcel1();



    }
```

Please let me know where i am missing .
My Excel sheet is like

user 1 pswd 1 (I want to write in this column)
user 2 pswd 2 (I want to write in this column)

When i run my code my output is like :
user 1 pswd 1
user 2 pswd 2

but when i open it overwrite previous data

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception

Comment: yeah thats what b'coz wb1 has no file passed to it. You can refer the link here for excel related things. [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just on a first glance your wb1 has no file passed to it. Also, you close wb, which is the object that Sheet1 and row both stem from, so you can't use them to write if wb is closed and wb1 has no file.